# Access to Smartcard with self-signed Java applet still possible?

Tags: java, security, applet, accesscontrolexception

Im trying to communicate with the client's smartcard using javax.smartcardio.
The applet is only for users within our Intranet.
The applet workings fine, when i debug it within Eclipse.

When i open it in the browser (i tried IE9 and Chrome) with following html code:

```
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script> 
    var attributes = {
        code:'test.TestClass',  width:300, height:300, scriptable:true} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'TestJNLP.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7'); 
</script>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
```

I get the following Exception:
[AccessControlException](http://s1.directupload.net/images/140130/uj4c3tvf.png)

The Java-Console only display this 3 lines:
    Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: file:/C:/AppletTestSite/TestApplet.jar
    Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: file:/C:/AppletTestSite/TestApplet.jar
    CacheEntry[file:/C:/AppletTestSite/TestApplet.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Wed Jan 29 08:40:39 CET 2014,length=6684

**Things i tried already:**

-using *doPrivileged*:

```
public void init() {
    try {
        AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Integer>() {
                    public Integer run() {
                        ReaderInit(); //<------
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
        // catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

-Adding permission to the jnlp-file:

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

-Adding following line to the manifest:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

-self-signed the jar-file with keytool&jarsigner

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>jarsigner -verify C:\AppletTestSite\TestApplet.jar
jar verified.
```

-in the java control panel, set Security Level to Medium and add the site's URL to Exception Site List

**Did i miss something or is it just not possible at all anymore(since the 1.7.0_51 update) to access the smartcard without a public trusted CA?**

I want to avoit changing the policy file for every single user of the applet.